# How to validate if Excel custom number format entered into winform is correct/working?

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms

I have a form with textbox, which if clicked, opens a dedicated inputbox (`Application.InputBox`). Inputbox is type2 (string type) and I use it to get custom number format from user. This custom format will be stored in settings and then used by another procedure.

How can I validate if entered number format (into inputbox) is correct "excel number format"? I could do it easily by changing number format of cell (`range.numberformat`) and checking it produces exception but I want to check it inside a form (so before the final procedure is run).

Is this possible? I have searched SO and other forums looking for clues but have found nothing so far.

PS I need this solution in .NET but I added VBA tag in case somebody done it in VBA. It might be useful for others as well.

Comment: What library are you using? What is correct `excel number format`? Can you give an example?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. As for the correct number format, it can be anything allowed by Excel pretty much, for example '#.##;-#.##'. If I have a free range (one cell), which I can use to test it then I can call Range.NumberFormat = X. If X is not allowed by Excel, it would produce an exception, which I can handle. The issue here is that I would like to test the validity of the specific number format when it is entered into inputbox, not later when this number format is used on a range.

Comment: Ah OK - I know this is VBA but is this the type? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat

Comment: Yes, this is the type. But I am looking for a way to validate custom number format without using a range from worksheet/workbook.

Comment: Sure makes sense, just double checking :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the InputBox has to do with it. I parsed to see if a valid number was entered. You will get leading and trailing zeros with this format string. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim numberStr = InputBox("Enter a number")
    Dim number As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(numberStr, number) Then
        numberStr = number.ToString("0.00")
    End If
    TextBox1.Text = numberStr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I think you missed the point. In inputbox you enter desired number format, not the number. I want to check if number format (string) inserted into inputbox (for example: '+#.## USD;-#.## USD') is a correct custom number format in Excel or if it is not and then do something (notify user for example). This can be done if you enter the number format into cell directly (if it is wrong then it produces an exception) but I would like to do it on a winform level.